# Configuring Exception Notification with Delayed Jobs in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job, exception-notification

I can't get the Exception Notification gem to notify me when a Delayed Job fails.  I can have jobs fail, but no notification is going out.  Anyone else figured this out?

I'm using:

```
delayed_job_active_record (4.0.0)
exception_notification (4.0.0)
```

And have the following in my initializers/delayed_jobs_config:

```
# Chain delayed job's handle_failed_job method to do exception notification
Delayed::Worker.class_eval do
  def handle_failed_job_with_notification(job, error)
    handle_failed_job_without_notification(job, error)
    # only actually send mail in production
    if Rails.env.production?
      # rescue if ExceptionNotifier fails for some reason
      begin
        ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.background_exception_notification(error)
      rescue Exception => e
        Rails.logger.error "ExceptionNotifier failed: #{e.class.name}: #{e.message}"
        e.backtrace.each do |f|
          Rails.logger.error "  #{f}"
        end
        Rails.logger.flush
      end
    end
  end
  alias_method_chain :handle_failed_job, :notification
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since exception_notification 4.0 [there's a new way to handle manual notify](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/tree/v4.0.0#manually-notify-of-exception). Try to change

```
ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.background_exception_notification(error)
```

for

```
ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(error)
```